# React Bootstrap Tooltip is not working on full screen

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, fullscreen, react-bootstrap

I have used the "Tooltip" tag that comes with React Bootstrap [React Bootstrap Tooltip and OverlayTrigger](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay-trigger). The code works well. However, when my app becomes fullscreen, I don't see the tool tips anymore. I am using React and React Bootstrap.

This is  the code for making the app fullscreen

```
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
```

And this is my tooltip

```
<OverlayTrigger
                    placement="top"
                    delay={{show: 250, hide: 400}}
                    overlay={DisplayTooltip(this.props)}>
                    <button onClick={(evt) => {
                        this.itemOnClick(evt)
                    }}>
                        {
                        <img src={this.props.icon} />
                    </button>
                </OverlayTrigger>
```

And the tooltip:

```
const DisplayTooltip = (props) => {
    return (
        <Tooltip id={props.tooltip_type + "button-tooltip"} {...props} appendTo>{props.tooltip_type}</Tooltip>
    );
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my colleague found a good solution that is working for the full screen issue. Now the tooltip is working fine

The solution is:

```
if (document.body.requestFullscreen) {
   document.body.requestFullscreen();
} else if (document.body.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
  document.body.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
  document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (document.body.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
  document.body.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```